# pandas pivoting DataFrame with two columns levels

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas DataFrame with two dimensions `region` and `products`, and two measures `cost` and `price`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
      {'region':['N', 'S', 'W', 'E', 'N', 'S', 'W', 'E'], 
       'product':['P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2'],
       'cost':[10, 13, 17, 28, 29, 23, 17, 18],
       'price':[7, 8, 4, 11, 9, 13, 7, 8]})
```

I want to obtain:

```
region      E                N            S           W    
        price cost   price cost   price cost   price cost
product                                            
P1         11  28     ...
P2          8  18     ...
```

I tried:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['product', 'region'])
       .agg({'price': 'first', 'cost': 'first'})
       .unstack('region')
       .swaplevel(axis=1)
print(df1)
```

But I get:

```
region      E     N     S     W    E    N    S    W
        price price price price cost cost cost cost
product                                            
P1         11     7     8     4   28   10   13   17
P2          8     9    13     7   18   29   23   17
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['product', 'region'])
       .agg({'price': 'first', 'cost': 'first'})
       .unstack('region')
       .swaplevel(axis=1)
       .reindex(columns=['E','N','S','W'], level=0))
print(df1)
region      E          N          S          W     
        price cost price cost price cost price cost
product                                            
P1         11   28     7   10     8   13     4   17
P2          8   18     9   29    13   23     7   17
```